# Does UILocalNotification fireDate Change After Set?

Tags: uilocalnotification

I am setting the `fireDate`s of my `UILocalNotification`s and grouping them by date in my `UITableViewController`. I am setting the `fireDate` property as a value in the notification's `userInfo` dictionary. Now, I want to edit the notifications, which consists of finding the specified notifications, deleting them, and then recreating them with the new `fireDate` value.

My question is:

When I set the `fireDate` value, with a `repeatInterval` set to `.Weekly`, does `fireDate` always contain the original value of `fireDate`, or does it update itself weekly when the notification is fired?

I could not find anything in the documentation for `UILocalNotification` that signals that it does in fact change. I am assuming that it always contains the original `fireDate` value, even after years of firing the notification weekly.

Can anyone point me to any available documentation that explains this, or at least confirm my conclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that my thoughts were correct in that the `UILocalNotification`'s `fireDate` property contains a value that corresponds to the `fireDate` that was initially set.

To test this, I created a `UILocalNotification` with a `fireDate`, waited a day after the notification fired, and then printed the `fireDate` value, which was the previous day's date (the date that I set the `fireDate` for).